# How to iterate subitems of QTreeWidgetItem in Qt

Tags: qt, iterator, qtreewidget

Qt provides QTreeWidgetItemIterator class to iterate through tree view's items.
There is even a constructor version which takes the item pointer instead of a view's. Unfortunately, even in this case, the iteration will go down to the very last item. Often, that is not expected behavior. If I start from the item, I want iterate only it's children and grandchildren. Of course, I could get another loop up the tree to check if I didn't go beyond the starting item, but that's ugly.
Is there way to do this nicely?

```
 QTreeWidgetItemIterator it(treeWidget);
        while (*it) {
            if ((*it)->text(0) == itemText)
                (*it)->setSelected(true);
            ++it;
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have the parent item to start with, then just loop through its children:

```
for (int i = 0; i < item->childCount (); i++)
{
    QTreeWidgetItem *child = item->child (i);
    // ... perform work here ...
}
```

I don't see an iterator that loops through an item's children, but there's really no need for it.

Comment: wouldn't it be too slow due to item->child(i) as an extra O(n) loop?

Answer (score 0):

A complete example :

```
QObject::connect(ui.treeWidget_2, SIGNAL(itemChanged(QTreeWidgetItem*, int)), this, SLOT(treeWidget2_itemClickedButtonAction(QTreeWidgetItem*)));

void treeWidget2_itemClickedButtonAction(QTreeWidgetItem* item)
{
    Qt::CheckState state = item->checkState(0);
    setChildState(item, state);
}

void setChildState(QTreeWidgetItem* item, Qt::CheckState state) {
    for (int i = 0; i < item->childCount(); i++)
    {
        QTreeWidgetItem* child = item->child(i);
        child->setCheckState(0, state);
        if (child->childCount() > 0)
            setChildState(child, state);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not what’s being asked? What’s about subchieldren?

Answer (score 0):

Kind of old question but I just stumbled upon. @goug answer is quite correct and it doesn't have any overhead (O(n) is literally the minimum you can achieve to access N elements and it is equivalent to an iterator solution). But if you dislike row indexing (as I do ) `QTreeWidgetItemIterrator` supports a wide variety of [filters](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreewidgetitemiterator.html#IteratorFlag-enum) so in most cases it is sufficient for me to write something like:

```cpp
QTreeWidget * tree;
QTreeWidgetItemIterator it(tree,QTreeWidgetItemIterator::HasChildren);
```

But with the exact description you gave I don't believe the filters are viable so I would do

```cpp
QTreeWidgetItemIterator it(treeWidget);
        while (*it) {
            while ((*it)->parent() && (*it)->parent()->parent()
                &&(*it)->parent()->parent()->parent())
                ++it; //while item has grand-grandparent skip it 
            //do things
            ++it;
        }
```

Comment: QTreeWidgetItem::child() doesn't have an extra loop as other pointed out already, but it can indeed cause some slowdowns, as it calls executePendingSort(). If you are editing the tree while iterating, each call to child() will trigger a sort. 
See [qtreewidget.h](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/itemviews/qtreewidget.h.html#187)